# What's the correct way to verify an SSL certificate in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to verify an SSL certificate in Win32 using C++.  I think I want to use the Cert* API so that I can get the benefit of the Windows certificate store.  This is what I've come up with.

- Is it correct?
- Is there a better way to do this?
- Am I doing anything wrong?

```c
bool IsValidSSLCertificate( PCCERT_CONTEXT certificate, LPWSTR serverName )
{
    LPTSTR usages[] = { szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH };

    CERT_CHAIN_PARA params                           = { sizeof( params ) };
    params.RequestedUsage.dwType                     = USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND;
    params.RequestedUsage.Usage.cUsageIdentifier     = _countof( usages );
    params.RequestedUsage.Usage.rgpszUsageIdentifier = usages;

    PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT chainContext = 0;

    if ( !CertGetCertificateChain( NULL,
                                   certificate,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   &params,
                                   CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN,
                                   NULL,
                                   &chainContext ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    SSL_EXTRA_CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_PARA sslPolicy = { sizeof( sslPolicy ) };
    sslPolicy.dwAuthType                       = AUTHTYPE_SERVER;
    sslPolicy.pwszServerName                   = serverName;

    CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_PARA policy = { sizeof( policy ) };
    policy.pvExtraPolicyPara      = &sslPolicy;

    CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_STATUS status = { sizeof( status ) };

    BOOL verified = CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy( CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_SSL,
                                                      chainContext,
                                                      &policy,
                                                      &status );

    CertFreeCertificateChain( chainContext );
    return verified && status.dwError == 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention what you're using this for, but yes, generally you should pass CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT if you're using this in a typical HTTPS scenario.

Comment: I mainly want to use this to verify LDAP server SSL certificates (like, inside of a VERIFYSERVERCERT function). I'm also thinking of using it to verify HTTPS server certificates in a client/server application where customers can specify their own SSL certificate for the server.

Comment: Is it more common to use CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT instead of CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN?  Why wouldn't you check the root certificate for revocations?

Comment: @EricLaw sorry for unsolicited ping but just wanted to draw your attention to the bounty on this question, I'd like to see a decent answer to this if you have the time/inclination to write one :-)

Comment: Sorry, @DaveRandom, I no longer have Windows source access and I don't have the confidence to provide a complete answer to such an important question. This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378740(v=vs.85).aspx explains some of the steps you must take. You might also want to look at the `VerifyRemoteCertificate` function in the public .NET Framework sources `_SecureChannel.cs`

Comment: This is me pledging **AN ADDITIONAL +250 BOUNTY** award for the best answer (on top of the current +250).

Answer (score 17):

You should be aware of [RFC3280 section 6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3280#section-6.1) and [RFC5280 section 6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-6.1). Both describe algorithms for validating certificate paths. Even though Win32 API takes care of some things for you, it could still be valuable to know about the process in general.

Also, here’s a (in my opinion) pretty trustworthy reference: [Chromium certificate verification code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/cert/cert_verify_proc_win.cc).

Overall, I think your code isn't incorrect. But here’s a few things I’d look into/change, if I were you:

## 1. Separate Common Name Validation

Chromium validates certificate common name separately from the chain. Apparently they've noticed some problems with it. See the comments for their rationale:

```
cert_verify_proc.win.cc:731 // Certificate name validation happens separately, later, using an internal
cert_verify_proc.win.cc:732 // routine that has better support for RFC 6125 name matching.
```

## 2. Use CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT

Chromium also uses the CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT flag instead of CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN. I actually started to looking into this before I found their code, and it reinforced my belief that you should use CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT.

Even though both aforementioned RFCs specify that a self-signed trust anchor is not considered part of a chain, the documentation for CertGetCertificateChain (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376078(v=vs.85).aspx) says it builds a chain up to, if possible, a trusted root certificate. A trusted root certificate is defined (on the same page) as a trusted self-signed certificate.

This eliminates the possibility that *EXCLUDE_ROOT might skip revocation checking for a non-root trust anchor (Win32 actually requires trust-anchors to be self-signed, even though it is not required by any RFCs. Though this is not officially documented).

Now, since a root CA certificate can not revoke itself (the CRL could not be signed/verified), it seems to me that these two flags are identical.

I did some googling and stumbled across this forum post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9f95882a-1a68-477a-80ee-0a7e3c7ae5cf/x509revocationflag-question?forum=windowssecurity. A member of .NET Product Group (supposedly) claims that the flags in practice act the same, if the root is self-signed (in theory, the ENTIRE_CHAIN flag would check the root certificate for revocation if it included a CDP extension, but that can’t happen).

He also recommends to use the *EXCLUDE_ROOT flag, because the other flag could cause an unnecessary network request, if the self-signed root CA includes the CDP extension.

Unfortunately:

- I can’t find any officially documented explanation on the differences between the two flags.
- Even though it is likely that the linked discussion applies to the same Win32 API flags under the hood of .NET, it is not guaranteed.

To be completely sure that it’s ok to use CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT, I googled a bit more and found the Chromium SSL certificate verification code I linked to at the top of my reply.

As an added bonus, the Chromium cert_verify_proc_win.cc file contains the following hints about IE verification code:

```
618: // IE passes a non-NULL pTime argument that specifies the current system
619: // time.  IE passes CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT as the
620: // chain_flags argument.
```

Not sure how they’d know this, but at this point I’d feel comfortable using CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_EXCLUDE_ROOT.

## 3. Different Accepted Certificate Usages

I noticed Chromium also specifies 3 certificate usages instead of 1:

```
szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH,
szOID_SERVER_GATED_CRYPTO,
szOID_SGC_NETSCAPE
```

From what I can gather through Google, the other usages can be required by older web browsers, otherwise they can fail to establish a secure connection.

If Chromium deems fit to include these usages, I'd follow suit.

Note that if you change your code, you should also set params.RequestedUsage.dwType to USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_OR instead of USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND.

—

I can’t think of any other comments at the moment. But if I were you, I’d check out Chromium source myself (and maybe Firefox too) - just to be sure I haven’t missed anything.

Comment: Will CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy api do revocation check for OCSP urls? It does not seem to do with normal options. Documentation does not mention anything about it. If I use CertOpenServerOcspResponse api a request is sent to the server. I can probably use that but still CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy fails with revocation check failure. Is there any option to make CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy do OCSP revocation check?

Comment: CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy revocation check using OCSP works correctly. But if you use the OpenSSL's built in OCSP command as server, make sure to set the -nmin value. Documentation for OCSP command says that no nmin means update is available immediately. Windows but thinks otherwise. Windows thinks there is no further update ever. so it will never check the URL again. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The latest code for Chromium no longer uses CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT. It is also much more complex than it used to be.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/cert/cert_verify_proc_win.cc#1136

Comment: The file has been deleted, here is the latest version they had https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/cert/cert_verify_proc_win.cc;drc=b0bac5d18ab47c553c7fb83e8e3c3ea8ff92fc16

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer depends on what exactly you are attempting to do.

I will caution you that SSL is based on the assumption that Both endpoints want a secure connection.  If either endpoint isn't interested in maintaining security then there is none.

Its a trivial effort to put byte codes in your distributed code that simply returns true for this function.  That's why windows moved a lot of validation into the kernel.  But they didn't anticipate people running windows on virtual hardware, which makes circumventing the OS just about as trivial.

Now consider that you expect to be provided a cert from some source, but pretending that that source couldn't be provided the same information from a reliable source.  And then hand it to you.  So You cannot rely on certificates to "prove" anyone is anyone in particular.

The only protection gained from certificates are in preventing outsiders, not endpoints, from breaching the confidentiality of the message being transported.

Any other use is doomed to fail, and it will fail eventually with potentially catastrophic results.

Sorry for the big post.  The comment section has a word limit.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, while the information contains is valid I was more hoping that someone could verify that the code depicted above is correct in the context of verifying certificates for SSL usage using the Windows crypto API. I am well aware of the limitations of SSL in these respects, but here I'm only really concerned with making my endpoint absolutely correct. For context, I've been working on [this patch](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/601) for the PHP core - so we're not worried about a specific application, only that the tools we're providing are correct.

Answer (score -1):

The functions `CertGetCertificateChain` and `CertVerifyCertificatePolicy` go together. This part is correct.

For `CertGetCertificateChain` the flag can be set to any of the following three if you want to check for revocation:

- CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_END_CERT
- CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN
- CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT.

Only one of them can be used, these three options cannot be `ORed`. Beside one of these flags you can consider how the chain should be created; using `local cache` or just `CRL` or `OCSP`. For these considerations [read this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_BC).

Error in executing the function or more simply if the return value is `0`, it does not mean the certificate is invalid, rather you were unable to perform the operation. For error information use `GetLastError()`. So your logic of returning false is wrong, it is more of a case of throwing the error and let the client code decide whether to try again or go on to do other stuff.

In [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749296%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_GenConsiderations) there is a section called "classify the error", please read that. Basically you should check `certChainContext->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus. Here a list of error statuses will be ORed. Please check CERT_TRUST_STATUS` msdn reference. So here you can have your business logic. For example, if you find the error status of the value (`CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN | CERT_TRUST_IS_OFFLINE_REVOCATION`) that certificate revocation check could not be performed, you have the option to decide what you want (let the cert go or still mark it as invalid).

So, before going to call `CertVerifyCertificatePolicy` you have the option to discard or already flag a validation error.

If you choose to come to `CertVerifyCertificatePolicy`, the chromium code is a wonderful reference regarding how to map policy_status.dwError to your error class/enum.